Still getting error after reviewing whole code again in Parcel while building
10:57:41 AM: Netlify Build                                                 
10:57:41 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:57:41 AM: ​
10:57:41 AM: ❯ Version
10:57:41 AM:   @netlify/build 29.41.1
10:57:41 AM: ​
10:57:41 AM: ❯ Flags
10:57:41 AM:   baseRelDir: true
10:57:41 AM:   buildId: 662dde2a400af40008ab9126
10:57:41 AM:   deployId: 662dde2a400af40008ab9128
10:57:41 AM: ​
10:57:41 AM: ❯ Current directory
10:57:41 AM:   /opt/build/repo
10:57:41 AM: ​
10:57:41 AM: ❯ Config file
10:57:41 AM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
10:57:41 AM: ​
10:57:41 AM: ❯ Context
10:57:41 AM:   production
10:57:41 AM: ​
10:57:41 AM: Build command from Netlify app                                
10:57:41 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:57:41 AM: ​
10:57:41 AM: $ npm run build
10:57:41 AM: > react@1.0.0 build
10:57:41 AM: > parcel build index.html
10:57:42 AM: Building...
10:57:45 AM: Bundling...
10:57:45 AM: Packaging & Optimizing...
10:57:46 AM:  Build failed.
10:57:46 AM: @parcel/optimizer-svgo: item doesn't belong to list
10:57:46 AM:   Error: item doesn't belong to list
      at List.remove 
10:57:46 AM:   (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@parcel/optimizer-svgo/node_modules/css-tree/lib/common/List.js:467:19)
10:57:46 AM:       at Object.exit 
10:57:46 AM:   (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@parcel/optimizer-svgo/node_modules/svgo/plugins/inlineStyles.js:297:44)
10:57:46 AM:       at visit 
10:57:46 AM:   (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@parcel/optimizer-svgo/node_modules/svgo/lib/xast.js:90:15)
10:57:46 AM:       at invokePlugins 
10:57:46 AM:   (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@parcel/optimizer-svgo/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/plugins.js:38:11)
10:57:46 AM:       at Object.fn 
10:57:46 AM:   (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@parcel/optimizer-svgo/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/plugins.js:105:14)
10:57:46 AM:       at invokePlugins 
10:57:46 AM:   (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@parcel/optimizer-svgo/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/plugins.js:31:22)
10:57:46 AM:       at optimize 
10:57:46 AM:   (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@parcel/optimizer-svgo/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo.js:55:13)
10:57:46 AM:       at Object.optimize 
10:57:46 AM:   (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@parcel/optimizer-svgo/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo-node.js:97:10)
10:57:46 AM:       at Object.optimize 
10:57:46 AM:   (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@parcel/optimizer-svgo/lib/SVGOOptimizer.js:56:25)
10:57:46 AM:       at process.processTicksAndRejections 
10:57:46 AM:   (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
10:57:49 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
10:57:49 AM: ​
10:57:49 AM: "build.command" failed                                        
10:57:49 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:57:49 AM: ​
10:57:49 AM:   Error message
10:57:49 AM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
10:57:49 AM: ​
10:57:49 AM:   Error location
10:57:49 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
10:57:49 AM:   npm run build
10:57:49 AM: ​
10:57:49 AM:   Resolved config
10:57:49 AM:   build:
10:57:49 AM:     command: npm run build
10:57:49 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
10:57:49 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/dist
10:57:49 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
10:57:49 AM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
10:57:49 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
10:57:49 AM: Finished processing build request in 27.622s

Checked whole code and it's working properly in local but while building(I used parcel bundler) it's showing
@parcel/optimizer-svgo: item doesn't belong to list
What should I do? I tried everything...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
